# How to store a zip file in sql server table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a problem and I do not know what to do. I am creating a application where the user can upload zip file. I want to  store this file in my database. On Google I was not able to find any real solution for this. In my database I created a field of varchar(max) to store this.  I am using C# and SQL server 2008 R2. Are there any solutions or guides that you can provide to me. >

Comment: How big the file will be? nvarchar wont be of help try blob or clob data types

Comment: You should be doing much more research on this.  Search for files table or filestream.

Comment: Since the ZIP file is  **binary** file, you need to use **`VARBINARY(MAX)`** - not `VARCHAR(MAX)` (which is a **textual** datatype!)

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe thanks for your comment in Google i read about blob but how to use this not any good article i found about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store and Retrieve .ZIP file in SQL SERVER 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961104/store-and-retrieve-zip-file-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Ultimately, a database is not the best storage for flat files, although it can of course be done; you might want to look at `FILESTREAM`, which compromises between the RDBMS world and file world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can not same file as nvarchar in database. Change the column datatype to varbinary.
2. From the code you need to convert your file to  byte[] as like below.

   `byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);`
3. Now save it into database as usual way.